# Adding Labels to Images with Openshift s2i Binary build

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, s2i

I would like to add some labels (commit hash, branch name,...) to images I create using Openshift source-to-image binary build. These labels will have naturally different values for every build.

Currently `oc start-build` does not even support -e flags to add environment variables. (At least is seems to, it works for Git source, its a bug?)

And for binary build does not supports `--build-arg` to pass argument for docker file.

The only way I was able to accomplish this to call `oc set env bc [build-name]` then start the build. And use Label in Dockerfile with values from environment variables.

My question is isn't there a better way to do this? (Ideally in a way that Dockerfile is not necessarily changed) Doesn't s2i supports passing `--label` to docker build behind?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add `environment variable` when you start `oc start-build` ? Because you mentioned `oc set env bc [build-name]`.
Then you can use `--env=<key>=<value>` option, refer [Starting Build](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/basic_build_operations.html#starting-a-build) for more details.

```
$ oc start-build <buildconfig_name> --env=<key>=<value>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: yes, that would be a little bit nicer solution. But --env / -e does not work for binary build for some reason - will create issue in github for them. (It works for Git source builds :O)